# Поиск одинаковых элементов списка и вывод списка с повторяющимися элементами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

У меня есть код который выводит количество одинаковых имён в списке, но мне так же нужно чтобы эти имена шли в новый список и на выходе получался массив с повторяющимися элементами. Помогите пожалуйста.
Пример: на входе ['Alex', 'Ighor', 'Alex', 'Djin']
на выходе ['Alex', 'Alex']
Нужна функция, не используя count.

```
   list_of_student = ['Alex', 'Ighor', 'Alex', 'Djin']
        def count_of_student(student):
            return list_of_student.count(student)
```

Comment: Нужно убрать из вопроса не относящийся к вопросу код и внятнее сформулировать задачу. Привести пример данных на входе и желаемый результат. Сейчас непонятно, что требуется и в чем проблема.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of_student =  ['Alex', 'Ighor', 'Alex', 'Djin']

[ i for i in list_of_student if list_of_student.count(i)>1 ]
['Alex', 'Alex']
```

---

```
def count_of_student(student):
    if list_of_student.count(student)>1:
        return student

[ count_of_student(i) for i in list_of_student if count_of_student(i)]
['Alex', 'Alex']
```

---

```
class Student():
    def count_of_student(self, student):
        if list_of_student.count(student)>1:
            return student


s = Student()

new_list = [ s.count_of_student(i) for i in list_of_student if s.count_of_student(i)]

print(new_list)
['Alex', 'Alex']
```

Comment: Простите, не работает, но всё равно благодарю...

Comment: а что именно не работает ?

Comment: Оно ничего не выводит) 
И ещё проблема в том что, list_of_student это строки, мы не можем их сравнивать с int...
Мне просто дали задание, создать школу на данный момент работаю над созаднием списков учащихся, и если есть похожие то их нужно вывести в отдельном списке... ну в общем, это наверное не столь важно

Comment: плюс, эти все методы будут делаться в классах...

Comment: Я добавил ваш метод в класс

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы выполнить задачу понадобиться для каждого элемента списка пробежаться по всему списку для выявления одинаковых элементов, если `count` не подходит, можно обойтись `len`:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]

print [i for i in a if len([j for j in a if j == i]) > 1]
# [1, 1, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Вы мне очень помогли, спасибо)